# how to get multiple array after a lookup in the same array

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I implement the same schema for parent and his child comment (first comment with response) Then, I apply the lookup to get all children, as it is shown the example:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6023bb8a61c8a308f0e3b955"),
    "interesting_comment" : [ ],
    "children" : [
        "0",
        "712c7588-6f8b-46a4-98f0-0902afaa883f",
        "f0c9d3ac-4926-4c0f-872f-28e7479f27c3"
    ],
    "updated_content_list" : [ ],
    "id" : "7839409b-5252-473b-b92c-c8a1a7f6626e",
    "author_id" : "1",
    "content" : "hello, new day and new chance  ",
    "creation_date" : ISODate("2021-02-10T10:55:06.563Z"),
    "__v" : 2
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6023bbbe61c8a308f0e3b956"),
    "interesting_comment" : [ ],
    "children" : [ ],
    "updated_content_list" : [ ],
    "id" : "712c7588-6f8b-46a4-98f0-0902afaa883f",
    "author_id" : "4",
    "content" : "take carhhhhhh555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555e too, thanks",
    "creation_date" : ISODate("2021-02-10T10:55:58.058Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6023bd1f61c8a308f0e3b957"),
    "interesting_comment" : [ ],
    "children" : [ ],
    "updated_content_list" : [ ],
    "id" : "f0c9d3ac-4926-4c0f-872f-28e7479f27c3",
    "author_id" : "4",
    "content" : "take carhhhhhh555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555e too, thanks",
    "creation_date" : ISODate("2021-02-10T11:01:51.503Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I try to get only parent with children, I implement this function:

```
async function ListComment () {
  const comments = await Comment.aggregate([
    { $unwind: { path: '$children' } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'comments',
        localField: 'children',
        foreignField: 'id',
        as: 'children'
      }
    }
  ])
  return comments
}
```

but I get separate arrays, I want to regroup them in the same array, any idea please

Comment: no need of `$unwind` stage, just do only `$lookup` stage.

Comment: Thanks for your help but in my case I don't need to treat comment with empty children field and to avoid this I add $unwind by default don't treat empty ones, I don't get any other idea to avoid traitement of comment with empty children field

Comment: You can put `{ $match: { children: { $ne: [] } } }` stage before `$lookup`

Comment: thanks a lot, it works